# Attaching hoses to outside faucet

Tags: faucet, hose

Is there an outside faucet thread that would make attaching a standard garden hose easy? Mine has a narrow thread that makes it very hard to get the attachment started. I spent over five minutes on my knees and gave up without ever getting the garden hose to attach. Others with more patience or skill can do it still so it's not the hose.

Comment: There are quick attachment systems for hoses.

Comment: you may have a damaged hose end